# Не компилируется в .apk python kivy linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, python-3.6, apk

Не компилируется код в .apk с linux ubuntu x64 через buildozer

Выводит:

```
build
running build
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/setup.py", line 2364, in <module>
main()
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/setup.py", line 2359, in main
"Tools/scripts/2to3", "Tools/scripts/pyvenv"]
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/setup.py", line 228, in build_extensions
missing = self.detect_modules()
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/setup.py", line 1562, in detect_modules
self.detect_ctypes(inc_dirs, lib_dirs)
File "/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/setup.py", line 1992, in detect_ctypes
print('Header file {} does not exist'.format(ffi_h))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd0' in position 30: surrogates not allowed
Makefile:618: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1

STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create —dist_name=myapp —bootstrap=sdl2 —requirements=python3,kivy —arch armeabi-v7a —copy-libs —color=always —storage-dir="/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" —ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
# CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
# LS_COLORS =
Custom Domain by Bitly
bitly.com

'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
# LC_MEASUREMENT = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
# LC_PAPER = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# LC_MONETARY = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
# LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
# MANAGERPID = '784'
# DISPLAY = ':0'
# INVOCATION_ID = 'f904150187854263bf5f4ea3faa6591a'
# GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
# COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
# USERNAME = 'soulhunter'
# XDG_VTNR = '1'
# SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
# LC_NAME = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
# USER = 'soulhunter'
# DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
# QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
# TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
# GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/4feb41c9_f538_4cbf_a04c_451a134b62b2'
# PWD = '/home/soulhunter/Документы/Coder'
# HOME = '/home/soulhunter'
# JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:19138'
# TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
# SSH_AGENT_PID = '1002'
# QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
# XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
# XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
# XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
# LC_ADDRESS = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=8162507702b8ce20e38a127a5e3ea93c'
# LC_NUMERIC = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
# WINDOWPATH = '1'
# TERM = 'xterm-256color'
# VTE_VERSION = '5202'
# SHELL = '/bin/bash'
# QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
# XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
# IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
# DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
# XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
# GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
# GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.84'
# SHLVL = '1'
# XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
# LC_TELEPHONE = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
# GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
# LOGNAME = 'soulhunter'
# DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=8162507702b8ce20e38a127a5e3ea93c'
# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
# XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
# XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
# PATH = '/home/soulhunter/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/soulhunter/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
# LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/soulhunter-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/906,unix/soulhunter-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/906'
# LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
# GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
# LC_TIME = 'kk_KZ.UTF-8'
# _ = '/home/soulhunter/.local/bin/buildozer'
# PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/soulhunter/.buildozer/android/packages'
# ANDROIDSDK = '/home/soulhunter/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
# ANDROIDNDK =

'/home/soulhunter/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
# ANDROIDAPI = '27'
# ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Простите за столько букв, просто я в линуксе не то, что чайник, а прожжённый самовар.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В пути к файлу не должно быть символов кроме латинцы и прилегающих и тогда всё работает